# How do I reverse the text in a file / stream in UNIX / Cygwin?

Tags: linux, command-line, cygwin

I have a block of text that I want to put in reverse-characer order (backmasking). Is there a simple way to do that via a Unix / Cygwin command-line?

Answer (score 1):

Use tac:

```
tac -r -s '.'
```

#### Examples

Reverse text from STDIN:

```
echo <YOUR TEXT GOES HERE> | tac -r -s '.'
```

Reverse text from a file:

```
tac -r -s '.' <FILENAME GOES HERE>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rev` is a bit simpler than `tac` (suggested by rmiesen). From the man page, the syntax is

`rev [option] [file...]`

If you omit the `[file...]`, it'll read from stdin. So if you want to reverse text in a string, you can do

`echo "some words backwards" | rev`

which outputs

`sdrawkcab sdrow emos`

Or the alternative syntax

`rev<<<"0123"`

outputs

`3210`

Answer (score 0):

A simple python thing, just for the giggles:

```
$ cat revline.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# Origin: https://superuser.com/a/1623168/346288

import sys

line=sys.stdin.readline()
while len(line)>0:
  print( (line.strip('\r\n '))[-1::-1] )
  line=sys.stdin.readline()
```

... and the output when run on itself:

```
$ ./revline.py  < revline.py 
nohtyp vne/nib/rsu/!#
882643/8613261/a/moc.resurepus//:sptth :nigirO #

sys tropmi

)(enildaer.nidts.sys=enil
:0>)enil(nel elihw
) ]1-::1-[))' n\r\'(pirts.enil( (tnirp
)(enildaer.nidts.sys=enil

$
```

*Oh, btw: `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 $HOME/bin/python` - assuming you have `$HOME/bin` in your `$PATH`- will make your life easier, assuming your python scripts are aware of python3*

*NOTE:* reverses line content, but not the **order** of lines.